# Update Chrome OS emulator for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

I am developing an application for Andropid with a min sdk of 30. I have no problems testing it on phone or tablet emulators, but I have not been able to do it for Chromebooks.

I have installed a Chrome OS Device emulator in Android Studio, but it only gives me the possibility to use a Nougat 7.1.1 as OS.

So when I run the application, it tells me that the minimum value of the sdk is higher than supported:

'The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.'

Is there a way to install a higher Chrome OS so that I can test the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Android emulator v30.0.10 includes a 13.5" Freeform AVD that supports resizable window on Android 11+, you should be able to use that for some tests.

Release notes: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#freeform_window_mode